# How to sort Pandas Dataframe by difference in Column A and Column B

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, sorting

```
Word    ControversialPost   TopPost
0   to  5756    4169
1   I   5717    4360
2   the 5416    4298
3   a   4929    3467
4   and 4071    2679
5   in  2814    1988
6   of  2771    1835
7   my  2325    1883
8   for 1989    1487
9   is  1961    1364
10  have    1713    1291
11  that    1552    1042
12  it  1452    1059
13  on  1404    1021
14  be  1302    1104
```

Above is my DataFrame, I want to sort by the difference between ControversialPost and TopPost. How would I do this?

I'm trying to do a sentiment analysis and see what words are most common and what words are not.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You could just add an extra column to your Dataframe called "Difference" and sort by that column. Something like this `df['Score_diff'] = df['ControversialPost'] - df['TopPost']`

Answer (score 0):

```
print(
    df.assign(tmp=df["ControversialPost"] - df["TopPost"])
    .sort_values(by="tmp")
    .drop(columns="tmp")
)
```

Prints:

```
    Word  ControversialPost  TopPost
14    be               1302     1104
13    on               1404     1021
12    it               1452     1059
10  have               1713     1291
7     my               2325     1883
8    for               1989     1487
11  that               1552     1042
9     is               1961     1364
5     in               2814     1988
6     of               2771     1835
2    the               5416     4298
1      I               5717     4360
4    and               4071     2679
3      a               4929     3467
0     to               5756     4169
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a col for the difference, then sort_values will do it.

```
df = pd.DataFrame([[1000, 950], [400, 300], [100,  80]], columns=['ControversialPost', 'TopPost'])
df['difference'] = df['ControversialPost'] - df['TopPost']
df = df.sort_values('difference', ascending=False)
print(df)


   ControversialPost  TopPost  difference
1                400      300         100
0               1000      950          50
2                100       80          20
```